# Binding Obj C to Xamarin project sharpie issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, binding

I'm trying to bind a native Objective-C SDK to my Xamarin project. I follow this tutoriel : [Walkthrough: Binding an iOS Objective-C Library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/)

Everything work till : Using Objective Sharpie. I generated the ApiDefinition and Strucs files but in my ApiDefinition, some class needs protocols.

```
    // @interface BIOEvent : NSObject <BIODiagnosticEvent>
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface BIOEvent : IBIODiagnosticEvent
{
    // -(instancetype _Nonnull)initWithType:(BIOEventType)type;
    [Export("initWithType:")]
    IntPtr Constructor(BIOEventType type);
}
```

For example here, the file doesn't found "IBIODiagnosticEvent". I have the impression that Sharpie didn't bind some headers files. Files which are @protocol

Could you help me please ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for those who have the same error. Xamarin add "I" convention before the name of the protocol. Just remove it.